# Missing } inserted. \end{split}

Tags: errors

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
${\delta _{k + 1}} = {\theta _{k + 1}} - {\theta _k}$ \\
\end{split} 
\end{equation}
```

I am using TeXstudio to write the equation. I am getting the following error. I am a beginner in latex

```
Missing } inserted. \end{split}
```

Where do I have to insert the `}`?

Comment: Try removing the two `$` signs.

Comment: I don't think you want the `$` inside the `equation` environment. There are also a number of spaces i.e.you want `\delta_{k+1}` with no space under before the underscore. Not sure about the \\ either

Answer (score 6):

You have spurious `$`'s inside `split`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}


\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
{\delta _{k + 1}} = {\theta _{k + 1}} - {\theta _k} \\
\end{split} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

BTW: If it is only line inside equation, `split` is completely unneeded.

Answer (score 2):

I’ve also eliminated unnecessary braces:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{amsmath}



\begin{document}

Some text.
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \delta_{k + 1} &= \theta_{k + 1} - \theta_{k} \\
        &= \text{there should be an alignment point, shouldn't it?}
    \end{split} 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This could have easily been a comment to [the other answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/329282/5764) instead...

Comment: @Werner: I sent my answer when the other one had not yet been posted (I think the server received it a dozen second after, or so).  I could delete it, but the sample code gets formatted better in an answer than in a comment… :-)  (*Note:* I immediately upvoted the other answer, anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

Avoid `$` , `\\` and line spacing

```
\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \delta _{k + 1} = \theta _{k + 1} - \theta _k
    \end{split}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.se.  Could you explain how your answer is different than the others?  (You may also want to look into its formatting.)